# How can I put this constraint into Python code?

Tags: python, list, constraints, z3, z3py

I am struggling to put the following constraints into python code using Z3 solver, but I am having a hard time. Could anyone please help?

The constraints:

- For every X there is at least one Y
- For every X there is at most one Y

I tried the below, but it is correct according to the constraint, since the code would only say: Count of x should be lower or equal to count of y.

```py
s = z3.Solver()

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]

e_count = len(x)
d_count = len(y)

s.add(d_count =< e_count)
```

The goal is to assign a y for every x (scheduling problem).

Comment: What is your variable `s`?

Comment: "it is not correct" is not an acceptable problem description. Please show us a (minimal) snippet of code that shows the problem and that we can run on its own, with all variables defined.

Comment: I edited the question to include more details. Sorry for the previous

Comment: I fixed the syntax error (`=<`) in your code and ran it. It does not throw any error. You still haven't explained the problem. Which additional code you are using is producing an incorrect result? Show us that code and explain how the result is incorrect.

Comment: The method I used in the example does not provide the desired constraint, the desired code is one that says: For every X there must be at least one Y, not like mine: Count of X should be lower or equal to count of Y. I hope I managed to make it a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to assign a free variable (called `picked` below) for each `x` value, assert that it's within the range of `ys`, and make sure they're distinct. Something like:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
ys = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]

# create a picked-value for each x
picked = [Int("picked_%d" % x) for x in xs]

# make sure it's within range
for p in picked:
    s.add(p >= 0)
    s.add(p < len(ys))

# make sure they're distinct
s.add(Distinct(picked))

# get a model:
r = s.check()
if r == sat:
    for (x, p) in zip (xs, picked):
       print(x, " -> ", ys[s.model()[p].as_long()])
else:
    print("Solver said:", r)
```

This prints:

```
1  ->  1
2  ->  2
3  ->  3
4  ->  4
5  ->  5
6  ->  6
7  ->  7
8  ->  8
```

So, unsurprisingly, the solver simply picked for each `x` the same value in `y`, as that obviously satisfies the constraints. Once you add further constraints, the model will become more interesting.

(Note that uniqueness of what `x` value gets matched to is by construction; we pick exactly one value for each `x`, and the `Distinct` constraint makes sure there are no repeats.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your goal is, but you will add boolean value, not a function, to your solver.
If I understand correctly, you want to prove that for every x there is at least one y.

Then you can:

```
y = set(y)
for i in x:
    s.add(i in y)
```

Comment: This is closer to what is needed. But, from my understanding, this code only adds the values from X that are existing in Y. While I need to assign at least one value (randomly) from Y to each X value.

Comment: Constructions like Python's `in` won't work for z3 symbolic values. Of course, this solution isn't even attempting to do what was requested; but that's something to keep in mind.